# Wordpress permalinks only work if logged in

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I have a strange issue in Wordpress (current version). When I set a custom permalink such as `/post/%post_id%`, it works *only* when logged in to Wordpress.

When not logged in, I get a 404 error (the route seems to get overwritten with `?p=%post_id%` which then fails to match the rewrite rules). I've tried all sorts of things without success (`.htaccess` is OK and permissions are fine). Does anyone have an idea?

On top of that, if I reset the permalinks to the basic pattern (`?p=` etc.), these do not work if not logged in either!

Answer (score 0):

This was my own stupidity! Wordpress does not allow access to 'future' posts if not logged in or privileged, by design.

There are ways to override this. The way I chose was to force 'published' status for future posts, which I want people to see as they are upcoming events.